# SQL ORDER BY Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is to obtain the top score of each player and the Time elapsed for that session.

In MySQL the following Query is used and works

```
SELECT Playername as 'Player Name', HighScores.P1Score as 'Highest Score', TimeElapsed as 'Elapsed Time'
FROM 
(gamerecord inner join playerprofile ON playerprofile.PID = gamerecord.PID),
(SELECT GID, PID, P1Score 
 FROM (SELECT GID, PID, P1Score 
       FROM gamerecord 
       ORDER BY 3 DESC) AS sortedtable 
 GROUP BY PID) AS HighScores 
WHERE gamerecord.GID = Highscores.GID
```

Now, when working with a MSSQL Server, the following error is thrown.

The `ORDER BY` clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless `TOP`, `OFFSET` or `FOR XML` is also specified.

The innermost query is used to sort the result first before the GROUP BY operation. It is observed that `GROUP BY` takes the top most value and thus by sorting, I make sure the top value is the highest score.

How may i make this work with MSSQL without that error being thrown?

Comment: In line 7, you must not use `ORDER BY 3 DESC`. Instead of `3`, you must use a valid column name. **EDIT:** Apparently, this is valid syntax (even I don't see the sense in it). The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: In MySQL, this is an undocumented solution (unless you count the comments section of the relevant page of the manual). Can you not use a documented solution.

Comment: @Michael Wagner `ORDER BY 3 DESC` is not what he expects it to be, but it's still valid syntax. You can just order by an expression, not column name only. That's not the cause of error.

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL server's TOP 'function'

Comment: @Strawberry I roughly understand the TOP function from the other questions on this topic. It returns the top x number of result of the table. However unless you specify the TOP as a ridiculously large number or 99.999999 percent, which seems like a hack, It will result in a loss of data when a lot of information populate the table.

Comment: @Strawberry with regards to the undocumented solution, I did so as I cannot find an alternative to the required result of the query. Unless I perform filtering post query on the application end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect a query that finds the maximum score for each game using `group`, and then joining in the rest of the information:

```
SELECT pp.Playername , gr.P1Score as HighestScore, gr.TimeElapsed 
FROM gamerecord gr inner join
     playerprofile pp
     ON pp.PID = gr.PID inner join
     (SELECT PID, max(p1score) as maxscore
      FROM gamerecord
      GROUP BY PID
     ) grmax
     ON gr.PID = grmax.PID and gr.p1score = grmax.maxscore;
```

`order by` is not appropriate for this type of query.

Comment: I dont see how this works nor does it work. GID is a unique identifier for each game played. Its the primary key for the gamerecord table. Thus `max(P1Score)` does nothing in this context.

Comment: I modified some of the names being used and it works. Thanks.